# Is it possible to control the zooming in TeeChart for a javascript?

Tags: javascript, teechart

we need to create some buttons to zoom in/zoom out. Also need to set zooming limitation. Is it possible to do these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using axis SetMinMax method as in the example [Yeray posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33103593/214639). Using SetMinMax you can set the zoom factor and also limit the maximum and minimum zoom levels.